# Example of uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying the sequence of functions, and I have a question!

I know the nowhere continuous function, Dirichlet function, that is,
$f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=0$, $x$:irrational, $f(x)=1$, $x$:rational.

But, I'm now stuck in the problem as follows:

1. For any national number $n$, $f_n$ is not continuous at any point of $[0,1]$.
2. ${f_n}$ converges uniformly to a continuous function on $[0,1]$.
   Give an example of a sequence ${f_n}$.

I have spent too much time due to this problem... I need your help. Thanks!

Comment: You could try modifying the Dirichlet function slightly for each of your $f_n$. Perhaps by changing the value that the irrationals take at each $n$? The limit of these functions can be very simple (e.g. a constant function is certainly continuous).

Comment: Yeah, in fact, I stated the Dirichlet function since this problem is related with the function I think. I tried your suggestion, but I failed. I imagine if I constructed a sequence by using the Dirichlet function, then this sequnce would converge uniformly to 0 on R.

Comment: I think you have the right idea but are having some trouble expressing it. Try letting $f_n(x)=0$ for the irrationals and $f_n(x)=a_n $ for the rationals, where $\{a_n\}$ is your favourite convergent sequence (you require strictly non-zero terms though) with limit $0$.

Comment: @fixedp That is a nice and full *answer* to the question. Indeed make it an answer, I would say.

Comment: Ah! I solve it now. It's so easy... I think I should require more studying! Thanks, have a nice day!

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness, I'll write my comment here.

Choose $\{a_n\}$ to be your favourite convergent sequence with limit $0$, taking care that none of the individual $a_n$ can actually be zero. Try letting $f_n(x)=0$ for the irrationals and $f_n(x)=a_n$ for the rationals.

Take care to prove that each $f_n$ is indeed now-where continuous and that the sequence of functions converges uniformly to the constant zero function.

Good luck.